# Find all values of $k$ such that $x^2+x+1$ is a factor of $x^{2k}+x^k+1$.

Tags: arithmetic

Find all values of $k$ such that $x^2+x+1$ is a factor of $x^{2k}+x^k+1$. I tried treating the first polynomial as a root of the other but didn’t get anywhere :(. I also tried substitution to get the second polynomial the resemble the first one but also didn’t get anywhere. Just $k=1$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "treating the first polynomial as a root of the other". Hint: the two roots of the first one must be roots of the second one.

Comment: Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega$ be a root of $x^2+x+1$, then write $$x^{2k}+x^k+1=(x^k)^2+(x^k)+1$$

The task has now been reduced to find out for which $k$ is $\omega^k$ a root of $$x^2+x+1$$

**Hint**:

> What is the value of $\omega^3$?

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers to such a FAQ.